# Min height and div growing as inner divs grow

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="col">

    </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:940px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:0;
}


.col{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 2000px;
    width:18%;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/om9xgrgz/2/)

I want the content to grow with the .col in height but if col is lower than 1000px content to remain in 1000px. Isn't that what min-height property does? I want to fill col with images that will have random height in different collumns so I am not sure the of the total height of its .col div.

Comment: What about your current code is not working? Are you clearing the float?

Comment: I need more than one collumns. My mistake. Updated my fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have floated the `.col` it doesn't expand the parents height. You need to clear the floats after the `.col` element. You may use the `:after` pseudo element to do this without adding additional markup :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/om9xgrgz/3/)**

*CSS :*

```
.content:after{
    content:'';
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}
```

Comment: Updated my fiddle, I need more cols than one to be one next to other.

Comment: @Apostolos it still is the same problem, the solution is to clear the floats : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/om9xgrgz/8/

Comment: If I wrap cols in a div.grid how can I make this div centered? I tried
.grid{width:100% margin:auto;} but didn't work

Comment: @Apostolos this is a different issue. You should ask an other question for it.

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.content{
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:940px;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom:0;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}

.col{
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 2000px;
    width:18%;
}
```

Has i understood is this what your look for

Answer (score 0):

Clear the floats-

```
.clr{clear:both}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/om9xgrgz/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

add clearfix below of .col

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col">

    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Then remove the `min-height: 1000px;` in .content

CSS for clearfix

```
clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear: both;
}

/*
 * For IE 6/7 only
 * Include this rule to trigger hasLayout and contain floats.
 */

.clearfix {
    *zoom: 1;
}
```